# Detection of the instantaneous position of the object shown to the camera in the browser

Tags: vue.js, browser, camera, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I am trying to detect ID cards using the Coco-Ssd model of Tensorflow.js on a web page developed with Vue.js. I put an svg image in the middle of the page as an ID card template. I want the ID card shown to the camera by hand to hover exactly over the svg image, and when the card hovers over the svg image, I want the user to continue the process and scan the back of the card. What I want to ask you here is how can I obtain the correct coordinate information of the card the user is holding?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTOA3.png)

I'm trying to reach the closest estimate using bbox information, but these coordinates do not include the current location information of the card on the page. If I can access the correct coordinates, I will try to reach the correct result by comparing it with the coordinates of the svg image. Anyone have experience with this issue before?